# Using Artifactory's REST API to deploy jar file

Tags: groovy, gradle, artifactory

Given this api [documentation](http://wiki.jfrog.org/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory%27s+REST+API#Artifactory%27sRESTAPI-DeployArtifact), how would I use HTTPBuilder and Groovy to construct my query? I've tried multiple things but I'm not getting it right.

```
def http = new HTTPBuilder()
http.request('http://artifactory:8888/libs-snapshot-local/my/jar/1.0/test-jar-1.0.jar', PUT, JSON ) { req ->

        body = [
            uri: "http://artifactory:8888/libs-snapshot-local/my/jar/1.0/test-jar-1.0.jar",
            downloadUri: "http://artifactory:8888/libs-snapshot-local/my/jar/1.0/test-jar-1.0.jar",
            repo: "libs-snapshot-local",
            path: "c:\\pathtojarfile\\test.jar",
            created: "2012-02-03T08:37:12.599-0800",
            createdBy: "someuser",
            size: "1024",
            mimeType: "application/java-archive"

        ]

    response.success = { resp, json ->


    }

  }
```

This seems to get me part way there, but it uploads an empty jar file. Seems like the body is completely ignored. Removing it produces the same result. I can't seem to find a good reference on how this is done.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The JSON in the mentioned documentation is actually Artifactory's ***response*** to the deployment request.
For deployment, Artifactroy requires only a simple PUT request, for example:

```
def restClient = new RESTClient('http://localhost:8080/artifactory/libs-release-local/')
restClient.auth.basic 'username', 'password'
restClient.encoder.'application/zip' = this.&encodeZipFile
def encodeZipFile(Object data) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    def entity = new FileEntity((File) data, 'application/zip');
    entity.setContentType('application/zip');
    return entity
}
def response = restClient.put(path: 'org/artifact/1.0/artifact-1.0.jar',
      body: new File('/path/to/local/artifact.jar'),
      requestContentType: 'application/zip'
)
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you! The documentation is a little confusing. Some of them say "Sample output" and some say "Sample usage". The Deploy api had "Sample usage".... which i thought would be how to call the api.