# Premature end of file when using RESTClient to upload xml file to Artifactory

Tags: groovy, gradle, artifactory

I'm trying to upload an xml file to Artifactory using their Deploy [api](http://wiki.jfrog.org/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory%27s+REST+API) call.

```
   def restClient = new RESTClient('http://localhost:8080/artifactory/libs-release-local/')
    restClient.auth.basic 'username', 'password'

    def response = restClient.put(path: 'org/artifact/1.0/awesome.xml',
          body: "<xml>xml content goes here</xml>",
          requestContentType: 'application/xml'
    )
```

The file uploads fine into artifactory, but I get the response below. This wouldn't be that big a deal, but since it's failing it's also failing my Jenkins build, even though everything seems to have uploaded correctly.

I've tried different combinations of mime types, but to no avail. Also tried to make the body of the REST call a File and encoded it as application/xml, similarly as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9224439/237925), but got the same response. Is there something I'm forgetting here?

```
Error parsing 'application/xml' response
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Premature end of file.
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:97)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1054)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:921)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:884)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:410)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:423)
    at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder.parseResponse(HTTPBuilder.java:561)
    at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder.doRequest(HTTPBuilder.java:494)
    at groovyx.net.http.RESTClient.put(RESTClient.java:162)
    at groovyx.net.http.RESTClient$put.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at promote_21e02jrq8a8k96od4iph54ed23$_run_closure1.doCall(D:\apps\jenkins\promote.gradle:158)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:272)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:884)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:410)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:423)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$ClosureTaskAction.execute(AbstractTask.java:457)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$ClosureTaskAction.execute(AbstractTask.java:445)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:63)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:48)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.CacheLockHandlingTaskExecuter$1.run(CacheLockHandlingTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess$2.create(DefaultCacheAccess.java:200)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:172)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:198)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.longRunningOperation(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:111)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.java:83)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.CacheLockHandlingTaskExecuter.execute(CacheLockHandlingTaskExecuter.java:32)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:41)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:243)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.executeTask(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:192)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.doExecute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:177)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:83)
    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:36)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:67)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter$1.run(TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter.java:31)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess$1.create(DefaultCacheAccess.java:111)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:126)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:109)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.useCache(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:103)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter.execute(TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter.java:29)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:67)
    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:152)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:108)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:76)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.execute(RunBuildAction.java:42)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.execute(RunBuildAction.java:28)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:21)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLoggingAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:238)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLoggingAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:222)
    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:48)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.EntryPoint$1.execute(EntryPoint.java:53)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.EntryPoint$1.execute(EntryPoint.java:51)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.Execution.execute(Execution.java:28)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at org.gradle.launcher.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:51)
    at org.gradle.launcher.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:24)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Premature end of file.
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at groovy.util.XmlSlurper.parse(XmlSlurper.java:146)
    at groovy.util.XmlSlurper.parse(XmlSlurper.java:199)
    at groovyx.net.http.ParserRegistry.parseXML(ParserRegistry.java:269)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    ... 85 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to do the trick. Can there be a bug in the RESTClient?

```
def http = new HTTPBuilder("http://localhost:8080/artifactory/libs-release-local/org/artifact/1.0/awesome.xml")
        http.auth.basic 'username', 'password'
        http.request(PUT, TEXT ) { req ->

            body = "<xml>xml content goes here</xml>"

        }
```