# How to use Artifactory REST API to deploy new artifact using Groovy HttpBuilder?

Tags: rest, groovy, artifactory

http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-DeployArtifact describes the REST API as:

```
PUT /libs-release-local/my/jar/1.0/jar-1.0.jar
{
"uri": "http://localhost:8080/artifactory/libs-release-local/my/jar/1.0/jar-1.0.jar",
"downloadUri": "http://localhost:8080/artifactory/libs-release-local/my/jar/1.0/jar-1.0.jar",
"repo": "libs-release-local",
"path": "/my/jar/1.0/jar-1.0.jar",
"created": ISO8601 (yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ),
"createdBy": "userY",
"size": "1024", //bytes
"mimeType": "application/java-archive",
"checksums":
{
        "md5" : string,
        "sha1" : string
    },
"originalChecksums":{
        "md5" : string,
        "sha1" : string
    }
}
```

How does one provide the contents of the file when using Groovy's HttpBuilder?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Artifactory's REST API to deploy jar file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9220753/using-artifactorys-rest-api-to-deploy-jar-file)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to interact with Artifactory from Java (or Groovy for that matter), I suggest using [Artifactory Java client](https://github.com/JFrogDev/artifactory-client-java).

If it misses some features you need, please let us know, we'll be glad to implement them.

If you still prefer to do it by yourself, take a look at the sources, that's exactly what we do.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I had tried using that client and ran into Groovy version issues.

Comment: Let me help you with that.

Comment: I'm looking through the source now. Thanks.

Comment: Great. GitHub issue with the details on the version conflict will be appreciated.